# How to invite people for talk on old questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10084/proving-rtlna-i-equal-to-non-pv-work-done-by-system-where-a-i-is-activity) that I asked on chemistry site ,but too less people viewed it with no response. .Now how to promote that question and invite people to discuss about it?

**NOTE** **--** I have less reputation so I can not put bounty on it.

Comment: You can ask around in [chat], or get enough rep and put up a bounty ;). Your question also needs some clarity improvements, I'll try to edit it

Comment: In short, we need a larger community.  We are still rather new, and therefore, we are still growing.  The best thing anyone can do if they really want answers to questions and in short time-frames is to invite anyone you know with expertise in Chemistry to join.  Some of us have been here since Area51 but we can only contribute so much (we don't know EVERYthing nor do we have an unlimited amount of free time to invest).